# SQL task if the product has no sales in the given month, then display 0 in this month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to build and SQL query which must do these things:

1. select all products from table "products" - satisfied
2. SUM all sales and forecast to the next 3 months - satisfied
3. check if the product has no one sale, then write "0" -> here is the problem, because I don't know how to do that..

My SQL query is here..

```
select product.name,
       (select sum(amount)
        from forecast 
        where forecast.product_id = product.id),
       sum(sale.amount)
from product join
     sale
     on sale.product_id = product.id
where sale.outlook > -4
group by product.id
```

Here is the products table:

```
    id  name
    1   milk
    2   roll
    3   ham
```

Table sale (same structure like forecast):

```
product_id  outlook amount
1           -1      9
1           -2      13
1           -3      14
2           -1      88
2           -3      61
3           -1      33
3           -4      16
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` to bring in the rows and `coalesce()` to get the `0` instead of `NULL`:

```
select p.name,
       (select sum(f.amount)
        from forecast f 
        where v.product_id = p.id),
       coalesce(sum(s.amount), 0)
from product p left join
     sale s
     on sale.product_id = product.id and
        sale.outlook > -4
group by p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand the requirement to be, show the sales per product and if no sale for a product show "0". Tables are named Products and Sale.
For this, "with" statements are useful and help understanding too:

```
With SalesSummary as
(
  select product_id, sum(amount) as ProductSales
  from Sale
  Group by product_id
)
select a.ProductID, ISNULL(b.ProductSales,0) as Sales
from products a left join SalesSummary b on a.product_id=b.product_id
```

Comment: can you please add these into "code element"?